# ClientFactory http client request stuck

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, httpclient, httpclientfactory

I'm developing .net core application. I try to use IHttpClientFactory to get HttpClient. 
I find out that sometimes for some requests method GetAsync stuck. At same moment if i use new HttpClient() it works fine

url:

> https://i.mycdn.me/image?id=879381309947&t=33&plc=API&aid=1246413312&tkn=*6UWxsdoE8PBzmpmnySW2C9DI064

This stuck

```
 HttpClient client = ClientFactory.CreateClient();
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(FileStorageOptions.RequestRemoteImageTimoutMilliseconds);
                var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

                return null;
```

This works fine:

```
using (var client2 = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(FileStorageOptions.RequestRemoteImageTimoutMilliseconds) })
                using (var result = await client2.GetAsync(uri))
                {
                    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        return await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                    return null;
                }
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run this code in a .NET Core console application without issue:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection().AddHttpClient().BuildServiceProvider();
    var clientFactory = services.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();

    var client = clientFactory.CreateClient();
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://i.mycdn.me/image?id=879381309947&t=33&plc=API&aid=1246413312&tkn=*6UWxsdoE8PBzmpmnySW2C9DI064");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: yeap, it's not always stuck. Some times its work, some times not